# Please help for whatsapp plus

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I tried to install whatsapp plus on my Gionee M2 but it shows some error as it says something like; files existing with the same name, I rooted my mobile and tried to unistall the app with titanium backup also but still the problem is persisting, please help, I am really keen to use the apop. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Just a tip. If your question has statements like "it says something like", you are going to get very open ended and vague answers to your question. Look at the current answer you have here as an example. If you don't want to take the time to clearly explain your problem and get the correct information, why would anyone spend the time to research and format a detailed answer for you.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the Whatsapp-related files on the SD card ?